# How can I get the full height of a web page that uses a master page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I'm writing a script that creates a popup that dims the screen behind the popup. I'm using JQuery's `$("#dim").css("height", $(document).height());` to resize the `div` element in question, but it doesn't cover the master page area. Is there a way I can get the height of the WHOLE page and not just the child page?

EDIT: The problem may actually lie in the positioning, and not the size, of my div. I have it set to `top:0`, but maybe I need to move it using javascript?

Comment: This does not really have anything to do with Master Pages. After the page has been built by ASP.NET, the clientside Javascript is unaware of what belongs to the MasterPage and what doesn't. It's all just HTML then.

Comment: Well, unless he's done something in either page which results in mangled markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var width = screen.availWidth;
var height = screen.availHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `.outerHeight()` isn't supported for `window` or `document`, you'll have to add the padding to the `height()` yourself.

```
$("#dim").css( "height", $(document).height() + 2*parseInt($(document).css("padding"),10) );
```